# MySQL Database connects, but says the name is incorrect

Tags: mysql, database, pligg

I am trying to install Pligg on my linux server, but am having difficulties.  I am at the point where I need to point Pligg to a SQL server, and setup the server on using these instructions:

http://codelikezell.com/setting-up-rails-mysql-php-apache-and-git-on-ec2/

Pligg asks for:

Database Name
Database Username
Database Password
Database Server 
Table Prefix

For Database Name, I use mysqld - which Putty confirms is running.  I login as root and the password I assigned, set the Server to localhost.

I get this error, however: Error: Connected to the database, but the database name is incorrect.

How can it connect to the DB if the name is not correct?  Am I doing something to point Pligg to the wrong DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Database name is not the same as process name(mysqld). Leave it blank or enter 'test' as db name; as far as I remember mysql always creates `test` database by default.

Comment: I deleted test in a previous step, Is there a quick method to create a new one>

Comment: It also must be `mysql` database.

Comment: I tried mysql as the database and it says it cannot find the server as opposed to it seeing the db with localhost, but the name being wrong.